# Text search on github files

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search

I am looking at creating text search capabilities on the files on multiple github repo. I am looking at options elastic search or logstash. Please suggest and point to any reference related to such examples. Thanks!

Comment: Github provides a search, i believe using elasticsearch. Are you looking for something extra?

Comment: Github uses elasticsearch, because of its distributed functionality needed for Github scale. Here is a good read: https://web.archive.org/web/20140209085653/http://exploringelasticsearch.com/book/elasticsearch-at-scale-interviews/interview-with-the-github-elasticsearch-team.html

Comment: @sramalingam24, my need is that I should be able to put across the search for group of repositories. Like, I have around 100 different repositories of similar content and I want to search over all 100 to pull out all matching full text.

Comment: That is built in too https://blog.github.com/2013-05-06-repository-search-on-all-repositories/

Comment: And here is the latest doc https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/

Comment: @sramalingam24, thanks for pointing those links, I will read through them.